# SQL Query to find maximum, average, minimum of temperature

Tags: sql

I was attending a question in hackerank advanced SQL certification, i came across a question like to find the maximum, minimum and average of temperature . i wrote query evrrything was perfect except Average

Below is my query

```
SELECT MONTH(record_date) , MAX(data_value) AS max,min(data_value) as min,
Round(sum(data_value)/count(data_value))  as avg

FROM temperature_records
Where Month(record_date)<=12 and Month(record_date)>=7
GROUP BY MONTH(record_date),data_type   order by MONTH(record_date);
```

Can anyone guide me on what was mistake in average .

Comment: You can use ```AVG``` function instead of formula which you have  used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the average function `AVG()` here:

```sql
SELECT MONTH(record_date), MAX(data_value) AS max, MIN(data_value) AS min,
       AVG(data_value) AS avg
FROM temperature_records
WHERE MONTH(record_date) BETWEEN 7 AND 12
GROUP BY MONTH(record_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(record_date);
```

Comment: I tried using avg function, but it was not giving me correct answer, i think i did a mistake with conditions . Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTH(record_date), 
MAX(data_value) AS max, 
MIN(data_value) AS min, 
CONVERT(int,ROUND(AVG(CAST(CASE WHEN data_type = 'avg' then data_value END AS DECIMAL)) ,0)) as avg 
FROM temperature_records 
WHERE MONTH(record_date) BETWEEN 7 AND 12 GROUP BY MONTH(record_date) ORDER BY MONTH(record_date);
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT MONTH(record_date), MAX(data_value) AS max, MIN(data_value) AS min,
       round(AVG(CASE WHEN data_type = 'avg' then data_value END)) AS avg
FROM temperature_records
WHERE MONTH(record_date) BETWEEN 7 AND 12
GROUP BY MONTH(record_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(record_date);
```

Try this

Comment: Is this unique from the already accepted answer? Looks like the `AVG` function was already the correct answer.

Comment: I was asked the same question in the Hackerrank quiz, according to the question, we need to find the average of the values of which data_type column value  is 'avg', so to get the exact answer, I have used the case condition. so I have submitted  this answer because the earlier wouldn't work for that scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Because there is a relation between data_type column and data_value column we may use the following syntax in Postgres:

    SELECT  EXTRACT(MONTH from (record_date)) AS month,
            max(data_value) filter (where data_type like 'max') AS Maximum,
            min(data_value) filter (where data_type like 'min') AS Minimum,
            cast(AVG(data_value) filter (where data_type like 'avg') as INTEGER) AS Average
    FROM    temperature_records
    WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from (record_date)) > 6
    GROUP BY data_type, record_date
    ORDER BY month, Maximum, Minimum DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT month(record_date),
         max(data_value),
         min(data_value),
         round(avg(case when data_type="avg" then data_value end))
    FROM temperature_records 
GROUP BY month(record_date)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       MONTH(record_date), 
       MAX(Case when data_type = 'max' then data_value End) AS max, 
       MIN(Case when data_type = 'min' then data_value End) AS min,
       round(AVG(CASE WHEN data_type = 'avg' then data_value END)) AS avg

FROM temperature_records
WHERE MONTH(record_date) BETWEEN 7 AND 12
GROUP BY MONTH(record_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(record_date);
```

Comment: Even this works well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
MONTH(record_date)
, MAX(data_value) AS max, MIN(data_value) AS min,

Cast( ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN data_type = 'avg' then 
CAST(data_value AS float) End), 0) as int )AS avg
FROM temperature_records
WHERE MONTH(record_date) BETWEEN 7 AND 12
GROUP BY MONTH(record_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(record_date);
```

Comment: right sql server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to avoid avg issue

```
SELECT MONTH(record_date) AS month,
MAX(data_value) AS max,
MIN(data_value) AS min, 
round(AVG(CASE WHEN data_type = 'avg' then data_value END)) AS avg
FROM temperature_records 
WHERE MONTH(record_date) BETWEEN 7 AND 12
GROUP BY MONTH(record_date);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    datepart(month,record_date) AS month,
    MAX(case when data_type = 'max' then data_value else null end) AS max_value,
    
    MIN(case when data_type = 'min' then data_value else null end) AS min_value,
    
    round(AVG(case when data_type = 'avg' then CAST(data_value as FLOAT) else null end),0) as avg_value
    
from temperature_records
group by datepart(month,record_date);
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so. Also, it seems like it doesn't differ much from already accepted answer, which suggested AVG() function, you just added parts of code that have nothing to do with what was asked in question.